# Correlation matrix and p-value combined in one matrix by column and row

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two matrices with the same dimensions and I would like to combine/merge them. I would like both matrices in the lower level of the combined matrix. 
There is an example in stackoverflow where they have two symmetrical matrices of the same lengths (one contains correlation coefficients and the other contains p-values).But is not quite what I want. Thank you!

Comment: "I would like both matrices in the lower level of the combined matrix." What?

Comment: So I have 2 matrices, and I want to merge them. The results should look like the correlation matrix in Minitab!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a minitab site. You're looking for a lower-triangular matrix. Like this in r:

```
data(mtcars)
cors <- cor(mtcars[ , 1:4])
cors[upper.tri(cors)] <- NA


            mpg       cyl      disp hp
mpg   1.0000000        NA        NA NA
cyl  -0.8521620 1.0000000        NA NA
disp -0.8475514 0.9020329 1.0000000 NA
hp   -0.7761684 0.8324475 0.7909486  1
```

But that doesn't give you pvalues with the coefficients. There was a recent article on r bloggers about the `sjPlot` package which seems to be what you want:

```
library(sjPlot)
sjt.corr(mtcars[ , 1:4], pvaluesAsNumbers = TRUE)
```

Gives me a nice html table that you can copy/paste into your favorite word processor or spreadsheet-er

[image]

I don't think there is support only for a lower/upper triangle, but like I said, you can edit the cells in your document.

Here's the link
http://www.r-bloggers.com/beautiful-table-outputs-in-r-part-2-rstats-sjplot/

Comment: Good idea to just print lower/upper triangle! This feature will be included in the next package update.

Comment: Your package has saved me a ton of time, @DanielLüdecke; one more thing, when you turn off the summary in `xtab`, it removed the bottom table border. I can add it back in with the CSS argument, but I'm not sure that was intentional. Should be a quick fix? `with(mtcars, sjt.xtab(cyl, gear, showSummary = FALSE)); with(mtcars, sjt.xtab(cyl, gear, showSummary = TRUE))`

Comment: I guess it was intentional, but you're right: it looks better if double bottom border is also shown if summary is hidden. I've fixed that, available in the next package update (or this evening at github).

Comment: @DanielLüdecke: it seems that the ```sjt.corr``` is deprecated. Do you know what can I use instead of it? Thanks in advance!